# Set global working directory alias in Git bash (Windows)

Tags: windows, alias, git-bash

I've been trying for literally hours to set a global alias that I can use when I open Git bash on my Windows machine to cd to a specific location.

I want to be able to simply type the alias to get to the location. I've tried every which way. The attempt that got me closest was based on this: https://superuser.com/questions/602872/how-do-i-modify-my-git-bash-profile-in-windows
...but it seems that to get it to work upon relaunching of bash, I have to use         `source .bashrc`, which I don't want to do. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just jury rigged a solution with a simple shell script that acts like a global alias. If someone has a better solution, please do tell.

Opened text editor and wrote the following two lines:

```
        #!/bin/bash
        cd blah/blep/directory_of_choice
```

Saved it as a text file with a descriptive name (like dirjump) somewhere and copied it.

In file explorer, navigated to the bin folder in the MinGW64 installation, e.g. "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin"

Pasted the file into this bin folder.

While viewing the contents of the bin folder referenced above in Windows file explorer, from the menu bar selected "view > options", which opened the "folder options" dialog. Selected the "view" tab here and unchecked "Hide extensions for known file types" and clicked ok.

Deleted the ".txt" extension from the file copied into the bin folder.

To call this shell script that has the same result as a global alias, typed the following in Git bash:

. dirjump (the space between the dot and the dirjump MUST be included)